# Store multiple contravariant delegates in a dictionary

Tags: c#, generics, contravariance

I have following statement:

```cs
private delegate ITask<Id> CreateObjectDelegateAsync<in T>(T @object)
    where T : Model.Object;
```

And I want to store that in a dictionary:

```cs
Dictionary<Type, CreateObjectDelegateAsync<Model.Object>>
```

Now I am getting errors since `T` is not covariant and he can't convert it. I have multiple delegates with a derived `T` that need to be inside that dictionary.

`T` must be invariant in order for it to be usable as a type in the parameters. Any ideas or workarounds for this?

Comment: You cant do this as you have discovered (Well you cant do it in a typed way at-least), i think you might have to rethink this whole use case a little.

Comment: So maybe store it as just a System.Delegate and casting it later?

Comment: I don't quite follow what the problem is. If you've fully applied the type argument (i.e. `CreateObjectDelegateAsync<Whatever>`), there shouldn't be any variance involved. Can you paste what the error is?

Comment: The problem is that I use generics that have derived types, not specific ones.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin i think this  `with a derived T` is the key here, which is why it wants to be contravention, and it just cant be.  Yes you will have to go down a less strictly typed / generic route

Comment: @S.Mense Do you just want a dictionary of functions that accept values that are subtypes of `Model.Object` and produce `ITask<Id>`? If so, does `Dictionary<Type, Func<Model.Object, ITask<Id>>>` work?

Comment: Oh right, you won't be able to assign any functions that demand subtypes of `Model.Object` to a `Func<Model.Object, ITask<Id>>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution was quite simple: While I can't do it with invariance here directly, I can just use a:

```cs
Dictionary<Type, Delegate>
```

instead. I can assign any delegate to that no matter the generic type. Then later when getting the delegate I will just need to cast it to

```cs
CreateObjectDelegateAsync<T>
```

again.

Like so (given that `T` is an existing type in the dictionary):

```cs
(CreateObjectDelegateAsync<T>)DelegateDictionary[typeof(T)]
```